# Increment integer field by 1 starting from a certain row

Tags: mysql, increment

table1: id, field1(integer), field2, ...

as shown above field1 is integer that is serialized from 1 to 100

I enter a new record where field1 value is 45 from php form. given that this value already exists in the table (from 1 to 100)

**I want the query to store the new record Before the existing one in the table and increment field1 values starting from the second 45 **

Thanks much for help!

Comment: put an example also with values.

Comment: if field1 value is already exists what you want to store?

Comment: field1 is a column in the table. I want to insert the new row, with field1 value is 45, then increment the rest of the rows downwards to 100. So the value of field1 in the last row would be 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against this. Normally, you should just insert rows in any order. If you want to sort, you probably will sort by a name, or by a relevant value.

If you want for some reason to have a particular sort order, then you can do it in two update statements:

1: Shift all the rows to make room for the new row.

```
UPDATE YourTable SET Field1 = Field1 + 1 WHERE Field1 >= 45
```

2: Insert the new row.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Field1) VALUES (45)
```

As you can tell, this can become inefficient, since you are actually updating all rows. If your table becomes larger, it will take more time to insert rows, especially at the beginning.

If you need you can optimize this a little, for instance, by keeping gaps between the rows. If you have a numbering in steps of 100, you can just insert the row at 4450, right between 4400 and 4500. You only need to renumber when there is no gap between the records where you want to insert the new row.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run 2 sql like wise

```
$input_value = "45";
$sql1 = "UPDATE table1 SET field1=field1+1 WHERE field1>='$input_value' ";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, ....) VALUES('$input_value', '$field2_value', ...); ";
```